# how to get type from key in mongodb collection on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Initially I import data in datatype **Hash**, in that i have a column called schedule, I need type of the particular column "schedule" from my db.
my tried code is

```
       schedule = scheduleWorld.all
       schedule.each do |sec|          
         sec.attributes.each do |key, value, type|
         puts "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"  
         puts  key
         puts  value
         puts  type
         puts "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"   
         end
       end
```

By this am getting nil in type, i tried another code is

```
  schedule = scheduleWorld.where({schedule:{$type=>2}})
```

error is

```
undefined method `specify' for nil:NilClass
(eval):2:in `where'
```

anyone have idea about this?

Comment: You don't say what RoR gem you're using but neither the mongo_mapper or mongodb gem define the global variable '$type'. So maybe it should read  `schedule = scheduleWorld.where({schedule:{"$type"=>2}})`

Answer (score 0):

Type is just one key-value pair in a mongodb document's attributes hash.
So you can always fetch it like this. I'm using Mongoid. 
The exact name may vary on you ORM.

```
       schedule = scheduleWorld.all
       schedule.each do |sec|
         type = sec.attributes["_type"]          
         sec.attributes.each do |key, value|
         puts "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"  
         puts  key
         puts  value
         puts "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"   
         end
       end
```